# How better organize logger for a class - static pointer field, global variable, singleton field, etc?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, static

I have some class and one field is a static pointer - let's say it's a logger, so I want it to be initialized and be same for all instances pf this class.

```
class A
{
private:
static Logger* logger;
};
```

And this logger will be initialized from the dll, so it's initialization is a function, I can't just write new or make_unique or whatever.
My question is how better to organize this and where to initialize this logger? Should I add `Logger * initLogger()` as a static method to the class and call it in the constructor like

```
A::A() {
    if (!logger)
    logger = initLogger();
}
```

Or maybe I better make this logger static variable in the cpp file, but then again I have the question when to call it's initialization function. Or write new class for a logger that will be singleton? I think it's pretty standard situation so there should be some best approaches?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to make it a function-scope static, which is guaranteed to be initialized only once:

```
Logger* getLogger() {
  static auto* logger = initLogger(); // done once
  return logger;
}
```

Comment: You can even return reference then normally.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was going to, but then you have to handle the `nullptr` case, so I left it as a pointer.

Comment: You mean without adding it to the class at all?

Comment: @Bruice You can make it a static function of the class, or a free-standing function. Whatever floats your boat.